# How do I concatenate these numbers in 8051 Assembly Language?

Tags: assembly, 8051

[image]

So in this picture I have the following numbers stored in different memory locations:

```
04 04 00 02 08
```

for my class, I have to somehow concatenate the individual numbers and make this into 44 and 28. I have no clue how to do this without hardcoding. Please help !

In pseudo code it would be something like:

```
     string str
     for i in range data_mem.length:
     while (data_mem[i] != 00):
     str += "data_mem[i]"
```

Comment: You mean `44` decimal, or `0x44` hex, just shifting and ORing together the bytes?

Comment: Either way, strings aren't a useful idea for this in assembly language; they're just arrays of bytes, and there is no `+=` append operation.  You have to manage the storage, like reallocate if necessary (like C++ std::vector) or use a large enough buffer in the first place. And a string would be made of ASCII bytes like `34 34` (that's `'4'` twice).  Thinking about your problem in terms of C (not a very-high-level language like Python) would give you something that does translate to assembly language directly.